# Add test controller and route to test event listener

Tags: symfony

How can I test event listener in the Symfony bundle?

I plan to test it with client (send request and get response). But I have no controllers in my bundle. Can I add 'special' controllers and routes from functional test and test output from them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found way how to add controllers for test.

First - create new controller class (I created it in %BundleName%/Tests/Controller)

%BundleName%/Tests/Controller/TestController.php

```
namespace %BundleName%\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function rootAction()
    {
        return new Response('This is home page');
    }

    public function galleryAction($id)
    {
        return new Response(sprintf('This is gallery %s', $id));
    }
}
```

Then I used this controller in test.

%BundleName%/Tests/Controller/PageControllerTest.php

```
namespace %BundleName%\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

class PageControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client
     */
    private $client;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = static::createClient();
        $this->client->followRedirects(true);
        $this->setUpRoutes();
    }

    public function testFirst()
    {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/gallery/42');
    }

    protected function setUpRoutes()
    {
        $container = $this->client->getContainer();

        /** @var \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router $router */
        $router = $container->get('router');
        $collection = $router->getRouteCollection();

        foreach ($collection->all() as $routeId => $route) {
            //Leave some routes if you need... 

            $collection->remove($routeId);
        }

        $controllerClassName = '\%BundleName%\Tests\Controller\TestController';

        $rootRoute = new Route('/', array('_controller' => sprintf('%s::%s', $controllerClassName, 'rootAction')));
        $galleryRoute = new Route('/gallery/{id}', array('_controller' => sprintf('%s::%s', $controllerClassName, 'galleryAction')));

        $collection->add('_test_root_route', $rootRoute);
        $collection->add('_test_gallery_route', $galleryRoute);
    }
}
```

On each test start setUpRoutes method clears route list and registers new routes. Each route _controller param value is `\%BundleName%\Tests\Controller\TestController::nameOfAction'`.